# Ionic background service when app killed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I need to run a background service in my Ionic application. I checked a plugin

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

but this plugin  only works when app is in background, when app is killed it does not work. If anyone have any idea please tell me.

Comment: no no, I am doing for Android for now.

Comment: hi, have you solved this issue? I'm fcing the same issue. can you help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/wiki/Build-your-own-Background-Service
when the app go to background its start play media in the background
so is like he full the device that he have process in the background
TRY THIS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: SO HELPFULL!, if this answer solve me thing i need to do should be more recognized.